# Python skipping a true if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to build a simple calculator app from scratch in Python as a school project, but the Python environment doesn't seem to accept my if functions.

This is my code:

```
# Calculator Script
print("At this moment this script is only able to support basic calculating like adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying a maximum of 2 numbers at a time.")

val1 = input("Enter First Value: ")
val2 = input("Enter Second Value: ")
print("First Value is "+ str(val1)+ ", Second Value is "+ str(val2))

print("Enter Calculation Operation!")
print("1: Addition")
print("2: Subtraction")
print("3: Multiplication")
print("4: Division")
clx = input("Enter your choice: ")

if clx == 1:
    clxprint = str("Adding")
    clx = str("+")
    print(str(clxprint))
if clx == 2:
    clxprint = str("Subtracting")
    clx = str("-")
if clx == 3:
    clxprint = str("Multiplying")
    clx = str("*")
if clx == 4:
    clxprint = str("Dividing")
    clx = str("/")
else:
    print("Error")
    exit()

print("Processing Operation...")
print(str(clxprint)+ " "+ str(val1)+ "by "+ str(val2))
```

As you can see, it is not complete yet, but I want to get rid of this problem first before I continue. After entering some placeholders for `val1` and `val2`, it doesn't seem to matter which option I enter as it always returns "Error".

Here is the full output:

```
At this moment this script is only able to support basic calculating like adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying a maximum of 2 numbers at a time.
Enter First Value: 1
Enter Second Value: 2
First Value is 1, Second Value is 2
Enter Calculation Operation!
1: Addition
2: Subtraction
3: Multiplication
4: Division
Enter your choice: 3
Error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Apart from the int/string issue, your `else` is executed whenever the condition in `if clx == 4:` is untrue, regardless of the previous if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

Python input() function return a string type. You're using clx as a string type and comparing it to some integer values, so the if statement is never true, and you always go to the 'else' statement.

To fix this, write as follow:

```
clx = int(input("..."))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Im new to python and i didnt know that this only works on integers...

Answer (score 1):

Gius's answer is correct. This is just a tip. Use `elif` instead of `if` where you can. In your code you have an `if` to check every possible clx value and while his is fine, you really should be using an `elif`. An `elif` is just an `else if` and doesn't start a new if code block. In your original code, your 4th `if` block will always run and so your error message might print even though one of the other options was selected. This will not happen with `elif`s

```
if clx == 1:
    clxprint = str("Adding")
    clx = str("+")
    print(str(clxprint))
elif clx == 2:
    clxprint = str("Subtracting")
    clx = str("-")
elif clx == 3:
    clxprint = str("Multiplying")
    clx = str("*")
elif clx == 4:
    clxprint = str("Dividing")
    clx = str("/")
else:
    print("Error")
    exit()
```

Also in your print statements, you don't have to convert all your variables with `str`, they are all already strings.

Comment: It does change the result in this case. Once the if statements from 1 to 3 get consumed it sees the if-else statement checking if it is 4. For the numbers 1, 2 and 3, the else statement will trigger and the script terminates.

Comment: Oh right, they way it was set up the 4 if statement would have always run and so it would have always sent an error. Good call

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you checking an integer and not a string?

Comment: Actually no, but would this make a difference? Sorry, im new to coding...

Comment: yes, open a python console and try 2 == "2", you will get False.